# Autoincrement и транзакции mySQL

Tags: mysql

Не знаю как грамотно смоделировать ситуацию, чтоб разобраться, поэтому спрошу:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Вставляю одним запросом большой объем данных, к примеру 10000 строк:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test (`value`) VALUES (1),(2),(3), ... , (10000);
COMMIT;
```

Если в это же время в другом потоке будет еще одна подобная транзакция, автоинкрементное поле будет значениями по порядку, без разрывов 1...10000 или перемешано со значениями из другой транзакции?

Можно ли гарантировано залочить БД на время выполнения запроса?

Что я делаю: нужно изредка вставлять большие объемы данных со связями many-to-many, но скрипт будет работать на shared-хостингах с ограничениями на запросы к БД и делать 10000 INSERT + 10000 LAST_INSERT_ID + ~30000 INSERT в связанную таблицу нет никакой возможности. Вот и придумываю как уменьшить количество запросов к БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам. Что бы ни происходило с базой данных, пока ты внутри своей транзакции - видишь только е изменения, что происходит внутри транзакции. Следовательно, нужно делать так:

```
START TRANSACTION;

/* Вставляем данные в основную таблицу */
INSERT INTO test (`value`) VALUES (1),(2),(3), ... , (10000);

/* Получаем список PRIMARY KEY 10 000 последних строк */
SELECT _id FROM 
    (SELECT id AS _id FROM `test` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100000) AS subq 
ORDER BY _id ASC;

/* На основании этих `_id` формируем новый запрос на вставку данных в связанную таблицу */
INSERT INTO pivot_table (`test_id`, `relation_id`) VALUES (...),(...), ...;
```

Получилось всего три запроса.

Comment: "пока ты внутри своей транзакции - видишь только е изменения" - в зависимости от уровня изоляции транзакций! Только свои - это Repeatable read. На Read committed будут и чужие зафиксированные.

Comment: @Мелкий верно. просто по умолчанию `Repeatable read`.

Answer (score 0):

При вставке одним запросом (а это атомарная операция!) блок значений автоинкремента резервируется ДО выполнения вставки. Так что никаких "левых вставок" от соседей по серверу не будет.

Лочить всю БД нет смысла - достаточно лочить только используемые таблицы.